# Ошибки при создании таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

При попытке создать таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE `Журнал ремонтних робіт`(
    `Номер по порядку` INT NOT NULL,
    `Інвентарний номер будинку` INT,
    `Номер ремонту` INT,
    `Час року` ENUM('зима','весна','літо','осінь'),
    `Рік` INT NOT NULL CHECK(`Рік`>=2000 AND `Рік`<=2099),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Інвентарний номер будинку`) REFERENCES `житловий фонд`(`Інвентарний номер будинку`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`Номер ремонту`) REFERENCES `вид ремонтної роботи`(`Номер ремонту`),
    CONSTRAINT `Номер по порядку` PRIMARY KEY (`Інвентарний номер будинку`,`Номер ремонту`)
)
```

выдает 2 ошибки

```
Найдено 4 ошибок при анализе.

Ожидалась запятая или закрывающая скобка. (near "CHECK" at position 215)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "`Рік`" at position 221)
Неожиданное начало выражения. (near "2000" at position 228)
Неизвестный оператор. (near "AND" at position 233)


#3780 - Referencing column 'Інвентарний номер будинку' and referenced column 'Інвентарний номер будинку' in foreign key constraint 'журнал ремонтних робіт_ibfk_1' are incompatible.
```

Подскажите, с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том что использовались разные типы данных во внешних ключах INT и INT(5) ZEROFILL

Comment: В таком случае предлагаю Вам отметить данный ответ как верный: для этого достаточно лишь нажать на галочку слева от своего ответа